# Como poner Botones dentro de Fragments para navegar un viewPager?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo 3 fragment que muestro dentro de un viewPager, pero quiero saber como poner botones dentro de estos para poder moverme, el problema es que no se como acceder al viewPager para mostrar el fragment seleccionado, quiero presionar un boton y mover al siguiente fragment y luego encontrarme alla que existe otro boton para regresar a la posicion anterior, como lo hago???

Esta es mi clase pricipal::

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int ACTIVITY = 4;
    private Context context = MainActivity.this;
    float x1, x2, x3, y1, y2;
    //Fragment
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Intent intent;
    private DepthTransform depthTransform = new DepthTransform();
    private ImageView cameraFragment, profileFragment, messageFragment;
    ImageView izquierdo, derecho;



    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: .............. Create MainActivity");


        setupViewPager();

    }

    public void setupViewPager(){

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_profile);

        List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

        SliderPagerAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, fragmentList);//

        sliderAdapter.addFragments(new CameraFragment());
        sliderAdapter.addFragments(new ProfileFragment());
        sliderAdapter.addFragments(new MessageFragment());

        //fragmentList.add(0, new CameraFragment());
        //fragmentList.add(1, new ProfileFragment());
        //fragmentList.add(2, new MessageFragment());

        viewPager.setAdapter(sliderAdapter);
        //MainView
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, depthTransform);
    }

}
```

Y este es uno de mis fragments::

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileFragment";
    private ViewGroup root;
    private  Context context;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ..................Create ProfileFragment");

        root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_profile, container, false);

        context = root.getContext();
        izquierdo =(ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.img_camera_profile);
        derecho = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.img_tools_profile);


        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //contentFrame = (Fragment) root.findViewById(R.id.fr_nav_profile);


Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.img_camera_profile).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Fragmento izquierdo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }
        });

Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.img_tools_profile).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                //@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Fragmento derechos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

    }
```

Presiono un boton en el fragment principal, pero no se como acceder desde un fragmento a la clase principal para manipular el `viewPager` para que este muestre el fragmeto que escogi al presionar el boton.

¿alguien sabe como hacerlo amigos?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien pero porque no usas un [tablayout](https://i0.wp.com/larntech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/TabLayout.gif?resize=266%2C446&ssl=1)?

Comment: Porque quiero usar botones para llamar al siguiente fragment en la siguiente posicion y poder regresar al pincipal, es algo similar a lo que hacer instagram con su camara y mensajeria!!!

Comment: estas duplicando la pregunta. Mejor muestra una imagen de como lo quieres, no se si te refieres a  3 puntos que se colocan en la parte inferior para navegar.

Comment: Parcero ya encontre la solucion, es super facil de hecho, y lo que yo hice fue mostrar 3 fragments en un viewpager y luego agregue botones dentro de cada uno de estos para asi poder moverme entre ellos, me entendes???